# How to capture selected row ID - MVC Table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have table layout in MVC (see below code), on each table row I have a submit button. Each Submit button post to same controller method 'TableSample'. How to capture the selected row id and post it?

```
public class TableSample
{
    public string Property1 { get; set; }

    public string Property2 { get; set; }

    public int Property3 { get; set; }

    public List<Things> Things;
}

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Property1)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Property2)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Property3)
<table>
    <tbody>
    @foreach (var thing in Model.Things)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@thing.ID</td>
            <td>@thing.Name</td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Select" name="Command" /></td>
        </tr>
    }
    </tbody>
</table>


[HttpPost]
public ActionResult TableSample(TableSample sample, string Command)
{
    if (Command == "Select")
    {
        //How to capture selected row ID?
    }

    if (Command == "Other")
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use javascript to catch the submit button click and place the row id in a hidden field, that way it will be submitted with the rest of the fields.

If the row id will not be part of your model you can simply add a parameter to the action method with the same name as the hidden field.

Let me know if you need more details.  I have done basically the same thing in one of my mvc applications.

Basically 3 steps:

1) Add the hidden input.  We'll just use straight HTML and not helpers since the field will not be part of the model.  Place this somewhere in the form:

```
<input type="hidden" id="rowId" name="rowId" />
```

2) Modify the action method signature to include the new parameter (I assume it is an integer but you can change the type accordingly if it is not):

```
public ActionResult TableSample(TableSample sample, string Command, int rowId)
```

3) Add the javascript to catch the submit button click and place the row id in the hidden field.  I prefer jQuery and I assume you have access to it since it's pretty standard for MVC 4:

```
$(function () {

    $('input[name="command"]').click(function () {

        // because there is a command button on each row it is important to
        // retrieve the id that is in the same row as the button
        $('#rowId').val($(this).parents('tr:first').children('td:first').html());

    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks. Sure. let me try first.

Answer (score 0):

It would be a little easy if you noted what you mean by rowID, bacause it is absent in you code. But for all I understand you mean id from first  of the row.

In Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult TableSample(TableSample sample, string Command, int rowid)
{
    if (Command == "Select")
    {
       rowid
    }

    if (Command == "Other")
    {

    }
}
```

In View:

```
<script>
    $('input[name=Command]').click(function(){
      var rowID = $(this).closest('tr').find(".rowid").val()
      $post('/Home/TableSample?rowid='+rowID+ '&Command=Select')
     });

    </script>

<table>
    <tbody>
    @foreach (var thing in Model.Things)
    {
        <tr>
            <td class="rowid">@thing.ID</td>
            <td>@thing.Name</td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Select" name="Command" /></td>
        </tr>
    }
    </tbody>
</table>
```